# Which of Saberhagen's non-berserker stories take place in the Berserker universe?

Tags: berserker

When reading most of Fred Saberhagen's fiction, I tended to assume that all stories without berserkers took place in a different universe.  Some certainly do, like *Pyramids* or *The Broken Lands*.

However, *Berserker Star* makes reference to the otherwise unrelated (and better) *The Veils of Azlaroc*.  Are there other stories without the killer robots that are nonetheless confirmed as taking place in the same 'verse?